# Concatenate a string from multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a view where an entry in my view is a concatenated string. In this case, it is `ParticipantNames`.

I have two tables. A `Trips` table and a `Participants` table. One trip can have one to many participants. So in my `Participant` table I have multiple rows that are related to a single entry in the `Trip` table.

Is it possible to create a string that concatenates the names from all the participants and insert that into the `ParticipantNames` column? e.g "Hans, Ben, Ali"

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW TripView 
AS
    SELECT
        Id  = Trip .Id,
        ParticipantNames = ???
    FROM    
        [dbo].Trip Trip 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [dbo].[Participants] Participants ON Participants.TripId = Trip.Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string_agg()` in the more recent versions of SQL Server:

```
 SELECT t.Id, string_agg(p.name, ', ') as ParticipantNames
 FROM  [dbo].Trip t LEFT JOIN 
       [dbo].[Participants] p
       ON p.TripId = t.Id
 GROUP BY t.Id;
```

Comment: Where should i write this? If i write it above where i am creating my view it says "CREATE VIEW MUST BE THE ONLY STATEMENT IN THIS BATCH"

Comment: You need a `GO` before the `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: Okay..and the thing you wrote where should i place it? It says: A fatal scripting error occurred.
Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO.

Comment: @Xraycat922 . .. This query seems syntactically correct.

Comment: What if I have multiple left joins can i still use that approach?

Comment: To answer my own question - yes you can.

Answer (score 3):

For versions earlier than SQL Server 2017, you can use FOR XML PATH, for string concatenation

```sql
SELECT 
    T.Id, 
    STUFF((SELECT ','+p.name
           FROM dbo.participants p
           WHERE p.TripId = T.Id
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS ParticipantNames
FROM [dbo].Trip T
GROUP BY T.Id;
```

From SQL Server 2017 onwards, you can go ahead with Gordon Linoff solution.